# How does iOS set X-Forwarded-For header in NSURLRequests?

Tags: ios, heroku, http-headers

I have an iOS app that makes calls to a python server that I host on heroku.

I can observe on the server that when I form a `NSURLRequest`, the `X-Forwarded-For` header is included on the incoming request.

However, in the iOS app logging `request.allHTTPHeaderFields` shows only headers that I explicitly added to the request.  It does not include the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Does anyone know if iOS is appending this header before sending the request, or is it being appended by my ISP provider, or heroku, or is it black magic?

From a logging/debugging perspective, can I assume that the ip address associated with the `X-Forwarded-For` header represents a unique user? If not, how should I interpret that ip address?

Note - I am not trying to use the value in this header for anything other than debugging, I've read about some of the perils of trying to use this for authentication, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This header is not sent by iOS, it's added by Heroku as well as some [other headers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers)

In general it's added by web server if request is proxied ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)).

In simple case `X-forwarded-for` will contain client public IP address.
If request is proxied before it reaches Heroku, then `X-forwarded-for` will contain a comma-separated list and first element will be client public IP address and next items are proxies public IP addresses.

Comment: Do you know if the ip-address in the header represents the actual ip address of the original client, or a proxy server?

Comment: It is client address - please read [this link i posted](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers): `X-Forwarded-For: the originating IP address of the client connecting to the Heroku router`

Comment: Thanks. I read that page before I asked this question on SO, but given that I'm not seeing the ip address passed from the client itself, I'm not sure how heroku determines the ip address and I'm curious if requests from a iPhone on the cellular network include the actual phone's ip-address or if it is a proxy based on which cell tower you are connecting through or something else.

Comment: Well if you are connecting over cellular network, your connection will most likely be proxied before it reaches Heroku. But it's not a problem - even then X-forwarded-for will contain list of IPs through which request came and first of those is public IP of client - in your case iOS device. Reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For#Format):

Comment: Thanks @Dariusz.  For completeness sake & future readers, what about over wifi? Do you know if the ip address is for the device or for the wifi router?

Comment: It will be router public IP. Each device will of course have private IP within LAN but outside they will share public IP of a router.